# Detect what is the location of the tap/press inside UIButton inside sender action method

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` stretched to the size of the view (covers the view/screen).

I have set a Touchdown action and I need in this action to find out what is the location of the tap/press on the button (get x and y coordinates).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the action function with `sender` and `event` params.  Then you can get the touch location on the button.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject, event: UIEvent) {
    // downcast sender as a UIView
    let buttonView = sender as UIView;

    // get any touch on the buttonView
    if let touch = event.touchesForView(buttonView)?.anyObject() as? UITouch {
        // print the touch location on the button
        println(touch.locationInView(buttonView))
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried, giving me this followng error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[beater.ViewController userbeat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15853200'

Comment: any ideas what is could be?

Comment: Something in your code is trying to call a function named `userbeat` in class `beater`.  However, the function `userbeat` does not exist or the `beater` object has been dealloc'd.

Comment: @IBAction func userbeat(sender: AnyObject , event: UIEvent) {            let buttonView = sender as UIView;
            
            // get any touch on the buttonView
            if let touch = event.touchesForView(buttonView)?.anyObject() as? UITouch {
                // print the touch location on the button
                println("what is this\(touch.locationInView(buttonView))")
            }

    }

Comment: oh lol the paste wasnt so well, dont know what is possible that went wrong because they both exist..

Comment: should i create another function or something or another connection from the button mybe?

Comment: Yes, on the storyboard, delete the existing connection and reconnect it.  The method signature has changed (because we added the event param) but it's still referring to the old method.

Comment: reconnect like i am doing as usuall? drag it to the code using split screens?

Comment: Works prefectly , you sir just made my day. i wish you good week !! !:)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3** version of accepted answer:

```
@IBAction func increaseButtonTapped(sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {

    // get any touch on the buttonView

    let events = event.touches(for: sender)

    for event in events! {

        let location = event.location(in: sender)

        print("\(location)")

    }

}
```