# Obtain location of UIButton press in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I have several drumpads set up on my view and they all connect to a drumPadPlay IBAction method.  I would like to determine the y-axis location of the user's press inside the sender button to adjust the volume the drum pad will play at.  I'm using swift.

Before this is flagged as a duplicate question I have referenced this question and the solution did not work for the current version of swift, or perhaps I don't know what to put where the answer says "buttonView".
[Detect what is the location of the tap/press inside UIButton inside sender action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994399/detect-what-is-the-location-of-the-tap-press-inside-uibutton-inside-sender-actio)

```
@IBAction func drumPadPressed(sender: BNDrumPad, event: UIEvent) {

    //...code for function here

    // get any touch on the buttonView
    if let touch = event.touchesForView(sender.)?.anyObject() as? UITouch {
        // print the touch location on the button
        println(touch.locationInView(buttonView))
    }

    //...more code for function here
}
```

Here is my code - the error is "use of unresolved identifier 'buttonView'"
I don't know what to use for buttonView.  I have tried sender.superview! and searched through sender's list of properties/functions and couldn't find anything that looked like it would help.

Comment: The answer you linked to is correct. Perhaps you could edit your question to show the code you tried and the error/problem you have.

Comment: I edited the question to include the code example.  I have a feeling it's such a simple answer the other answer assumed it would be known what to replace buttonView with but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sender` is a `BNDrumPad` which is (presumably) a subclass of a UIView, so in this case you will just use `sender`.  In the answer you linked to, the `sender` parameter was defined as `AnyObject` so they had to cast it to a `UIView` first.

```
@IBAction func drumPadPressed(sender: BNDrumPad, event: UIEvent) {

    //...code for function here

    // get any touch on the buttonView
    if let touch = event.touchesForView(sender)?.anyObject() as? UITouch {
        // print the touch location on the button
        println(touch.locationInView(buttonView))
    }

    //...more code for function here
}
```